# Prevent jQuery dialog submitting twice

Tags: jquery, double-submit-problem

I would like to prevent user from submitting dialog form twice.

Here is my submit code:

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    if (dialogSubmitted) { return false; }
    dialogSubmitted = true;
    ...
    ...
});
```

Where dialogSubmitted is a variable indicating if the form is already submitted. The problem is that it doesn't work. When I open the dialog and I press Enter twice (quickly) the form is submitted twice.

Any idea?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is another attempt which also failed when I press enter key twice very quickly:

```
    $('form', dialog).one('submit', function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        $(this).on('submit', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        });

        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
            $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
            ...
            ...
        }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {
            $('.modal-body p.body').html(error.responseText);
            writeError('msgError', pStopIndex.validationFailed);
        });

        // Unbind form submitting
        $('form', dialog).unbind();
        return false;
    });
```

As you can see, I do ajax post (in place of classic form submit). Maybe the problem is there?

Here is the capture of traces from Google Chrome:

[image]

We can see there are 2 posts. Only occurrs when I press enter key twice quickly or click submit button twice quickly.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What about DISABLING the submit button BEFORE getting to POST `$('#button').attr('disabled','disabled');` I do this and it works better than storing a variable becasue of the very reason you are experiencing. Disable the button and you cant press it twice quickly.

Comment: @ppumkin: good idea but what if user submit by pressing the enter key? Even if the submit button is disabled the user can submit by pressing the enter key? Correct?

Comment: @bronzatio ... ummmmmm. Not sure lol :) Never tried that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `one()` method

see example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MpBCL/

```
$('form', dialog).one('submit', function (evt) {

    /* prevent default action */
    evt.preventDefault();

    ...
    /* code to be executed once */
    ...

    /**
     * disable default action (this handler will be attached after first 
     * submit event and it will prevent any further submit action
     */
    $(this).on('submit', function (evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

further reference: http://api.jquery.com/one/

> **Description:** *Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.*

Comment: never knew about that :) nice one

Comment: Yes nice but I noticed that if I quickly pressed enter key twice, my form is still submitted twice. Possible?

Comment: @Bronzato I've included an example fiddle if this helps

Comment: Thanks. I try your solution and updated my question to show you more code because my code is more complex than your fiddle example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: remove your `$('form', dialog).unbind();` and `return false`... this should be no longer necessary

Comment: You point me to the right direction with your last comment. My problem is solved. Thank you very much.